# Downloading DeviantArt : Favourites, Groups, Gallery... 

Tags: command-line, web, download

Is there any command-line Linux tool for downloading user favourites (including subfolders), selected users galleries, groups ? (Preferably with ability to run in incremental mode, to update rip from time to time with new entries without reloading all currently loaded stuff)

I mean tool with DenvianArt web page parsing (web scraping) capabilities. So result will be a tree of direcotries with picture files in maximum available resolution:

```
userX_galleries/
    gallery1/
      pic_1_PICNAME.jpg
      pic_2_PICNAME.png
      (...)
      pic_n_PICNAME.jpg
    gallery2/
      pic_1_PICNAME.jpg
      pic_1_PICNAME.png
      (...)
      pic_n_PICNAME.png
    (...)
```

Or something like that.

Comment: Example gallery full of Arch64 screenshots: http://crimesaucer.deviantart.com/gallery/

Answer (score 1):

Either `wget` or `curl` should do what you want.  You will need to provide the right URLs to either tools.  To get the parsing, you could do that yourself via either picking the right file extensions or post-parsing of the files.

Comment: Ok, what you propose it about downloading web page or all related pages. Downloading gallery involves going thru many pages of gallery and into each of picture and selecting download of big version if available, if not downloading biggest available.

Comment: I understand what you are asking.  I am telling you how to make such a tool: `wget`, `find`, and `file` should get you most of the way there.  I am 99% sure that such a tool does not exist and that you will have to write it yourself.

Comment: there are a lot of web_scrappers (like BeautifulSoup or SeleniumHQ) as framweworks for crawling web pages. My point is not to reinvent the wheel, but to use working tool or base on similar.

Comment: BeautifulSoup is not a web scraper.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTTrack. There are both command line and GUI interfaces.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Httrack

http://www.httrack.com

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.